# PayPal SDK - C# - Receiving Payments

Tags: c#, paypal, sdk

Does the PayPal SDK supports receiving payments via a paypal account and money is transferred from a bank account?

Comment: What have you tried?  Do you need the documentation on the PayPal SDK, or do you have it and can't find your function, or have you tried a function and it doesn't work?

Comment: I have seen the documentation , but a little bit confused what SDK API to be used. 

is this the CapturePayment API ? or CreateInvoice API? Which is best recommended API to be used?